# My Context Menu Is Gone For Edit Mode And Object Mode

Tags: customization, shortcut

Something weird happened and I cannot seem to trace what's causing it.

By default, when you want to switch between *Object Mode* and *Edit Mode* you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the context menu appears right?

Well mine is gone. When I press tab,  I will immediately go to *Edit Mode*, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and back to *Object Mode* without having that pie menu.

This is happening on my laptop. I checked if it's something to do with the file so I opened the same file on a desktop and there it is, it's working properly. I see the context menu when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is this a setting I screwed up accidentally?

To clarify, in the screenshot below, I no longer have the option to see those menu when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will automatically switch to *Edit Mode*.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Tab, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be this option in the preferences:

[image]

Comment: thanks. that's really strange because I never recall changing this setting.